# como usar Chart.js con Angular 15?

Tags: angular, chart.js

estoy tratando de utilizar chart.js para graficar en angular 15 pero no entiendo porque no puedo mostrar las graficas, he visto diferentes tutoriales y pues no me funcionan, este es el código que he probado hasta el momento.

En el documento de html tengo esto

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

y en el documento .ts tengo esto

```
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';

    ngOnInit(){
      const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
      const myChart:any = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    
      const data = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'My Dataset',
          data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      };
      const options = {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      };
      const chart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: options
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar instalas con :

```
npm install chart.js
```

En el documento .html agregas el componente de  debes de escribir un id, en este caso el id es "ctx":

```
<div style="width: 800px;"><canvas id="ctx"></canvas></div>
```

Esto se debe de colocar en el documento de typescript:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'

ngOnInit(){

  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
//"ctx" hace referencia al id del componente canvas

  const myChart = new Chart("ctx", {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              y: {
                  beginAtZero: true
              }
          }
      }
  });
}
```

Solo seguí la documentación :
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html